# spring-boot setup basic auth on a single web app path?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, basic-authentication, spring-boot

I am trying to setup a single path (/basic) in my spring-boot spring MVC based application to be basic auth protected. I am just going to configure this using my own custom configuration parameters so the username and password are simply "admin" and "admin".

This currently works for the /basic path (I am prompted and can login correctly). The problem is that logout does not work (and I am not sure why) and also other paths (like /other shown) are being asked for basic auth credentials (before always being denied).

```
static class MyApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/open").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/other").denyAll(); // Block it for now
         http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/basic").authenticated().and().httpBasic().and().logout().logoutUrl("/basic/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

I expected /other to always be denied but I don't get why basic auth is coming up for it. /open works as expected. I also don't understand why /basic/logout does not log me out (it also does not produce error messages). I do have a simple bit of code as a placeholder for the logout endpoint but if I do not have that then I get a 404. The "home" view is my web app root so I just want to send the user there after logout.

```
@RequestMapping("/logout")
public ModelAndView logout() {
    // should be handled by spring security
    return new ModelAndView("home");
}
```

UPDATE:
Here is the solution that seemed to work in the end (except the logout part, still not working):

```
@Configuration
@Order(1) // HIGHEST
public static class OAuthSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/oauth").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().denyAll();
    }
}

@Configuration
public static class BasicAuthConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/basic").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
        http.logout().permitAll().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/").invalidateHttpSession(true);
        //.and().logout().logoutUrl("/basic/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i'm not sure about the logout, but we had a similar problem with having some of our site under basic and some of it not.  Our solution was to use a second nested configuration class only for the paths that needed http basic.  We gave this config an @Order(1)..but i'm not sure if that was necessary or not.

Updated with code

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth, Config appConfig) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser(appConfig.getString(APIConfig.CONFIG_KEY_MANAGEMENT_USER_NAME))
            .password(appConfig.getString(APIConfig.CONFIG_KEY_MANAGEMENT_USER_PASS))
            .roles(HyperAPIRoles.DEFAULT, HyperAPIRoles.ADMIN);        
    }



    /**
     * Following Multiple HttpSecurity approach:
     * http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity 
     */
    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ManagerEndpointsSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .antMatcher("/management/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().hasRole(HyperAPIRoles.ADMIN).and()
            .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Following Multiple HttpSecurity approach:
     * http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#multiple-httpsecurity 
     */
    @Configuration
    public static class ResourceEndpointsSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {        



       @Override
       protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {                  

            http
            //fyi: This adds it to the spring security proxy filter chain
            .addFilterBefore(createBBAuthenticationFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
            ;      
       }
    }
}
```

this seems to secure the actuator endpoints at /management with basic auth while the others work with a custom auth token header.  We do not prompt for credentials (no challenge issued) though for anything..we'd have to register some other stuff to get that going (if we wanted it).

Hope this helps

Comment: So you have 2 WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (or something similar)?

Comment: Awesome. I used a variant of that which I put in the question above. I am still not able to get the logout part working though. I am going to vote up your answer though because it helped me solve part of the problem.

Comment: Why do you need logout for the HTTP basic? The HTTP Form logout you can proceed with the normal setup. A full example can be seen in this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774742/spring-security-http-basic-for-restful-and-formlogin-for-web-annotations/27833237#27833237

Answer (score 1):

only one path will be  protected

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user"))
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ManagerEndpointsSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/add/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().permitAll()
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .and().csrf().disable();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```