# Spring Security HTTP Basic for RESTFul and FormLogin (Cookies) for web - Annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

**In Specific**

I want to have HTTP Basic authentication ONLY for a specific URL pattern.

**In Detail**

I'm creating an API interface for my application and that needs to be authenticated by simple *HTTP basic authentication*. But other web pages should **not** be using HTTP basic but rather a the *normal form login.*

**Current Configuration - NOT Working**

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http //HTTP Security
            .csrf().disable() //Disable CSRF
            .authorizeRequests() //Authorize Request Configuration
                .antMatchers("/connect/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/", "/register").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("API")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and() //HTTP basic Authentication only for API
                .antMatcher("/api/**").httpBasic()
           .and() //Login Form configuration for all others
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and() //Logout Form configuration
                .logout().permitAll();

}
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Waited for 2 days and didn't get any help here. But my research provided me a solution :)

**Solution**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable()
                    .antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "API")
                        .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/lib/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable() //HTTP with Disable CSRF
                    .authorizeRequests() //Authorize Request Configuration
                        .antMatchers("/connect/**").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/", "/register").permitAll()
                        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and() //Login Form configuration for all others
                    .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                        .and() //Logout Form configuration
                    .logout().permitAll();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I remove that basic http auth popup. I have tried everything but unable to do so.

Comment: don't use httpBasic, use formLogin.

Comment: tried that with no success, I disabled it by httpBasic().disable() and used formLogin(), but does not seem to be fixed.

Comment: Post your code in a separate question and put the link. don't forget to put your config source code to it.

Comment: Why do you use @Order annotation?

Comment: If you don't use "Order" you will get an error like the following one: Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique

Comment: The `Order` annotation defines the order in which the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` classes get processed.

Comment: @FarajFarook tell me please: Is it possible to use your approach to login to rest api by POST, returning 201 on successful and generating session ID ? Help me please,  I am fightening with this a long time

Comment: Could you please elaborate the mistakes and correction that made your expectation ..?

Answer (score 0):

I dunno if it can be helpful but I couldn't implement the above solution. I found a workaround defining a single Security

> @Configuration class

extending

> WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

with both httpBasic() and formLogin() configured. Then I created a custom

> CustomAuthEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint

that has this logic in the commence method:

```
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException
   {
        String urlContext = UtilityClass.extractUrlContext(request);
        if (!urlContext.equals(API_URL_PREFIX))
        {
            String redirectUrl = "urlOfFormLogin"
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + redirectUrl);
       }
        else
        {
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
```

Dunno which is the "best practice strategy" about this issue