# Spring security and angular

Tags: spring, spring-security, jwt

I'm working on this Application, it uses single page architecture using angular 2.
I'm building web app and mobile app for the mobile app.
I've an api module, which authenticates the user using JWT(Json web token)
should I use the same JWT for webapp too? or use regular spring security login with jsession and cookie

Comment: you can use them both, this is an example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278283/why-is-formlogin-with-second-precedence-not-working-when-configured-with-httpbas

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use jwt for webapp as well as for mobile app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you definitely can. Here is a good starter for Angualr1 + springboot + JWT.
https://github.com/bfwg/springboot-jwt-starter