# Spring oauth2 and digest authentication will work together

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I have added spring oauth2 into my restful service. Most of the services are consumed by my own portal so getting the token then calling the api is fine. However i have exposed some more web services which has to be called without this token concept. Those consumers have username and password.

The best example is Swagger implementation. Where opening the swagger page should be authenticated via digest instead of oauth token.

The below code changes i made but it is not working.
I believe, i no need to call oauth server from the resource server in this case. So just made the below code within the resource server. But seen the problem like after authentication page accepted my credentials it is again rerouting/redirecting to the same authentication page.

Please help.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerImpl extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {


    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {    
        http.anonymous().disable().requestMatchers().antMatchers("/**").and().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/url1/path1/path2").hasAnyAuthority( "FUNCTION_FN1")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/url2/path1/path2").hasAnyAuthority( "FUNCTION_FN2")
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and().formLogin().and().httpBasic()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }
}


@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class OAuth2SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I dont think this is possible to make some request to be authenticated with DIGEST and some are with OAUTH. So currently i made swagger url also to be authenticated with oauth token, instead of digest support.

Comment: You didn't provide any code regarding config, so why would you ask *What code changes i have to do?*

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Sure, i will provide, but is that feasible ...?

Comment: *However i have exposed some more web services*-- so the end-points are different for other's consumers and oauth2 consumers, right?

Comment: Yes, Ataur. URL is different but service is single one, but i want the same access rules (authorization) to be followed in both cases.

Comment: Means in the same resource server web service; i want some of the rest url  has to be authenticated with digest based.. instead of `?access_token=3e18b792-d4cc-40a5-9203-305e83ba6813`

Comment: Since you didn't provide any code, so you can apply for one `antMatcher()` for `httpBasic()` and another one token based `antMatcher().access()`. You can try that.

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna I have tried it but no luck.

Comment: You need to provide separate configuration for httpBasic(). refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774742/spring-security-http-basic-for-restful-and-formlogin-cookies-for-web-annotat

Comment: @vsoni Thanks! Let me check though I need digest authentication with mix  of oauth configuration.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's definitely possible to configure multiple authorization mechanisms in the same application. Distinct instance of  `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` should be provided for each mechanism.
`@EnableResourceServer` and `@EnableAuthorizationServer` provide corresponding oauth adapters. `ApiSecurityConfiguration` provides adapter for basic auth.

Here is minimal working sample for `basic` and `oauth2`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApp {

    @RestController
    public static class Endpoints {

        // doesn't require any authentication
        @RequestMapping("/test")
        public String test() {
            return "no auth";
        }

        // requires basic authentication
        @RequestMapping("/api/test")
        public String apiTest() {
            return "basic auth";
        }

        // requires oauth authentication
        @RequestMapping("/oauth/test")
        public String oauthTest() {
            return "oauth";
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public static class ApiSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/api/**")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").hasRole("USER")
                    .and()
                    .httpBasic();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                    .withUser("user")
                    .password("password")
                    .roles("USER");
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public static class AuthServerConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory()
                    .withClient("test")
                    .secret("test")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                    .authorities("USER")
                    .scopes("read", "write", "test")
                    .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                    .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.requestMatchers().antMatchers("/oauth/**")
                    .and()
                    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/oauth/**").authenticated();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

`pom.xml`

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```