# Configuring Spring Security for Form Login AND RESTful API

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security

I have looked at the many setup guides and questions posted here but am not able to find a solution for my problem. I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33739359/combining-basic-authentication-and-form-login-for-the-same-rest-api), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774742/spring-security-http-basic-for-restful-and-formlogin-cookies-for-web-annotat/27833237) and a few others.

I can't quite figure out the problem with my setup here. I have a web application that uses formLogin to authenticate from a login page. At the same time, other calients can access some of the services through a REST API.  All RESTful calls are made to /app/api*. Everything but /app/api should authenticate through formLogin (ie /app/* except for /app/api)

My REST authentication works if I disable formLogin (comment it out). The same if I comment out my REST securiting config; my formLogin works. I am not sure where the two are conflicting with each other.  My thinking on this is this: because of the order, basic auth will first attempt to authenticate but since none of the URLs are applicable, it will automatically fall to the formLogin authentication. 
Here is my setup:

**DispatcherServlet**

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean dispatcherServletRegistration() {
    DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet = dispatcherServlet();   
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext applicationContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    dispatcherServlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

    ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet, "/app/*");
    servletRegistrationBean.setName("Dispatcher Servlet");
    servletRegistrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return servletRegistrationBean;
}
```

**Basic Auth for REST**

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)                                                        
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

            @Autowired
        private MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests() 
                .antMatchers("/app/api/balance")    .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/api/callback/**").access("hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasIpAddress('::1') or hasIpAddress('0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1') ")
                .antMatchers("/app/api/**")
                .hasAuthority("API_USER") 
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        }
    }
```

**Form Login**

```
@Configuration   
@Order(2)
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private LogoutHandler logoutHandler;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/app/login", "/app/home", "/app/loginProcess","/app/logout", "/app/registration/new").permitAll()  
                .antMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
            .and()
                    .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/app/login")
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/app/loginProcess")
                .usernameParameter("email") 
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/landingPage")
                .failureUrl("/app/login?login_error=1")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                    .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .addLogoutHandler(logoutHandler)
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .permitAll()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                    .accessDeniedPage("/access-denied.xhtml")
                .and()
            .csrf()
                    .disable() 

                .sessionManagement()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/app/login");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/js/**", "/css/**", "/images/**", "/app/javax.faces.resource/**");
        }
    }
```

The problem is that, when I try to login from the login page, I get a 404 on http://localhost:8080/gsms/app/loginProcess.  It is as if only the basic auth is running.

Thank you.