# Spring Security 5 - Enable both Form Login and Basic Auth for multiple URLs with different user roles

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I need to be able to login to my app **through a form and through a REST API test tool like Postman using Basic Auth**.
I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774742/spring-security-http-basic-for-restful-and-formlogin-cookies-for-web-annotat) to a similar problem, however, I was only able to extend it to support one user role:

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class BasicAuthWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/course/addCourse", "/course/addTeacherToCourse", "/teacher/addTeacher", "/user/removeRole", "/user/addRole")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}

@Configuration
@Order(2)
public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/register", "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/login").permitAll()
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").hasRole("DEV")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/addAGradeForStudentInCourse", "/grade/addGradeForStudentInCourse" ,"/addAStudent","/student/addStudent","/addAStudentToCourse",  "/student/addStudentToCourse", "/teacher/allTeachers").hasRole("TEACHER")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/showAvgGradeInCourse", "/course/avgGradeInCourse", "/course/allCourseData", "/course/showByCourseNameAndThenAvgGrade", "/showTotalAvgGradeFromAllCoursesForAStudent", "/student/totalAvgGradeFromAllCourses", "/showAvgGradeForStudentInCourse", "/student/studAvgGradeInCourse", "/student/allStudents").hasRole("STUDENT")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/addACourse", "/course/addCourse", "/addATeacherToCourse", "/course/addTeacherToCourse", "/addATeacher", "/teacher/addTeacher", "/addUserRole", "/removeUserRole", "/user/removeRole", "/user/addRole").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
}
```

How would I go about extending the `BasicAuthWebSecurityConfig` `configure()` method to support multiple user roles like the one in `FormLoginWebSecurityConfig` `configure()` method?

Comment: You could do it in the same way. Add URLs with roles like in the second configuration.

Comment: I've tried that initially but its not so simple, as it breaks the form login. I think I will just add `/api` to my REST Controller paths and disable csrf and run basic auth on those URLs.

Comment: Sure it breaks your form login, because you didn't allow form login in your first configuration. If you want both for all URls, you only need one configuration.