# Spring-Boot REST service basic http auth exclude one endpoint

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a REST-only micro service built on Spring-Boot version 1.5.4.RELEASE with spring-boot-starter-security. The service has no web pages, just JSON in and out. The username and password are configured in the application.properties file. With credit to http://ryanjbaxter.com/2015/01/06/securing-rest-apis-with-spring-boot/ the following configuration causes the server to implement basic HTTP authentication quite nicely, it accepts the credentials and rejects unauthorized requests:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests() //
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();        
    }
}
```

My question is that I'd like to exclude one little ole path, one tiny endpoint, from basic HTTP authentication.  From frantic googling and SO copy-pasting I revised the above to have this:

```
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests() //
        .antMatchers("/healthcheck").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
```

This compiles and runs without warning, but that path is not opened for unauthenticated access.  I still must supply credentials to check the service health.

Do I have to match paths one by one? My little healthcheck endpoint is at the base of the context path, as are a whole bunch of others - adding paths one-by-one would be a hassle.

The relevant part of my application.properties file is:

```
security.user.name = web-user
security.user.password = web-pass
management.security.roles=SUPERUSER
```

Maybe I need to fiddle roles somehow?

Please help, thanks in advance.

Update 1:

Path information - I'd like this path (and many more at root) to be guarded:

```
localhost:8081/abcd/user
```

And I'd like ONLY this one path to be open, no auth required:

```
localhost:8081/abcd/healthcheck
```

Update 2: Looks like I largely duplicated this 3-year-old question, but no answer was accepted there for my issue:

[spring-boot setup basic auth on a single web app path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658285/spring-boot-setup-basic-auth-on-a-single-web-app-path?rq=1)

Comment: could you post the full url request that generates the problem?

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24696717/spring-security-permitall-not-allowing-anonymous-access

Comment: /healhtcheck is not /abcd/healthcheck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well after more experimenting I found that the following works - @efekctive please note that there is no context prefix on the healthcheck:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
     .antMatchers("/healthcheck").permitAll()
     .antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and().httpBasic();
}
```

One big caveat: when I posted this I was testing the healthcheck endpoint by invoking curl with BOGUS http credentials, expecting Spring to ignore them, but Spring always answered 401-unauthorized.  The proper test is to invoke curl with NO http credentials at all, then the healthcheck endpoint answers quite happily.

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work for me. Just fyi, i am using sessionCreationPolicy instead of httpBasic

Answer (score 2):

I have added the following to the SecurityConfig in my Springboot service and it works fine, I was able to exclude some endpoint from the basic auth.

```
@Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/customers/**/hints", "/customers/**/search", "/customers/**/clientConfig");
    }
```

Comment: This code snippet does not show a call to method authorizeRequests(). In your service do any endpoints require authorization?

Comment: I do configure basic auth on all the endpoints and swagger by the following code
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.httpBasic() // it indicate basic authentication is required
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/swagger-ui.html**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated();
    }

Answer (score 0):

You say your link looks like:

```
localhost:8081/abcd/healthcheck
```

Try this:

```
http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests() //
    .antMatchers("/abcd/healthcheck").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().httpBasic();
```

Comment: Thank you @JavaBoy for the very fast reply but no joy yet.. I used that code, tested by requesting that endpoint with curl without supplying any credentials; the response is 401 unauthorized.

Comment: Have you tried with @EnableWebSecurity on your class?

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8646

Comment: I see the same behavior whether @EnableWebSecurity annotation is present or absent on the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter class.

Comment: Check the bottom of this page: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html#production-ready-health-access-restrictions